# changing activity on sliding the screen

Tags: android

i have three activities in my application .

first one is the default activity when i slide right to left second activity should be open with its layout and when i slide left to right third one should open with its layout
i want to change the activities on sliding not only background or layout..
give me appropriate way to do this.

i m using this tab view but this is not giving any slider functionality

```
public class TabDemo extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_host);

        TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
        // no need to call TabHost.Setup()        

        //First Tab
        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("activity 1");
        spec1.setIndicator("activity 1");
        Intent in1=new Intent(this, activity 1);
        spec1.setContent(in1);

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("activity 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("activity 2");
        Intent in2=new Intent(this,activity 2);
        spec2.setContent(in2);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome in Resident center",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("activity 3");
        spec3.setIndicator("activity 3");
        Intent in3=new Intent(this,activity 3);
        spec3.setContent(in3);

        tabHost.addTab(spec1);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use Activities for this; use Fragments. See a detailled sample at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to create an App with Swiping functionality is in my opinion to create a new Android Application via Eclipse Wizard with following options selected:

1. Create `Activity` -> BlankActivity
2. Navigation Type = Tabs + Swipe

This will create an Application with (i think) 3 pages you can swipe through.
Now you can check the created files/code and change whatever you want/need to.

And as mentioned in the comments to your answer, this isn't possible with `Activites`, you need to use `Fragments`!